# GettingF response in Retrofit with protocol=http/1.1, code=200 in android studio while using immulator

Tags: android, node.js, api, retrofit

I am calling an API from nodejs localserver. API is calling but there is no data in Retrofit's respose.body. code == 200 and message==ok

I am getting following response:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://10.0.2.2:5000/getUserList}
```

com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.Model.VideoUploadModel@dcf1332

**in response.body()**

**APIService**

```
@GET("getUserList")
        Call<VideoUploadModel> getUsers();
```

**API call**

```
APIService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
    //        Call<VideoUploadModel> call = service.uploadVideoFile(MultipartRequester.fromString(video_title), MultipartRequester.fromFile("videoFile", mFilePath));
            Call<VideoUploadModel> call = service.getUsers();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<VideoUploadModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<VideoUploadModel> call, Response<VideoUploadModel> response) {
                    Log.e("get video called ", String.valueOf(response));
                    Log.e("get video called ", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    Log.e("get video called ", String.valueOf(response.body()));
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        VideoUploadModel videoUploadModel = response.body();
                        if (videoUploadModel.getSuccess() == "1"){
                            Log.e("videoUploadModel", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                            Log.e("videoUploadModel result", String.valueOf(videoUploadModel));
                            onSuccess();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.e("videoUploadModel not su", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<VideoUploadModel> call, Throwable t) {
    
                }
            });
```

**POJO class**

```
        package com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.Model;
    
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
    
    public class VideoUploadModel {
        @SerializedName("success") private String success;
        @SerializedName("name") private String name;
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public String getSuccess() {
            return success;
        }
    
        public void setSuccess(String success) {
            this.success = success;
        }
    
    }
```

**Nodejs API**

```
        app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '16mb' }));
        app.use(cors());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.get("/getUserList", function (req, res) {
            console.log("getUserList called");
            res.json({success: "1", name:"Rakesh"})
                // userController.userList(req, res);
        })
```

What is the issue? please check once.

Comment: "there is no data in Retrofit's respose.body" -- what do you mean by this? What does `getSuccess()` return? If you add the OkHttp logging interceptor to your Retrofit configuration, what does the raw response look like?

Comment: Getting code = 200 and message = ok but not receiving the json which sent from backend in API

Comment: What does `getSuccess()` return? If you add the OkHttp logging interceptor to your Retrofit configuration, what does the raw response look like?

Comment: @CommonsWare Really thanks, actually I was loggin the model object, instead of getter, now its solved. Thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set status in your server application

Example :

```
     res.status(200).json(your response data object)
```

Comment: okay, but I am getting code =200 already.

Comment: Still getting same issue. Anything else?